# Why does String(null) work?

Tags: javascript, string, null, tostring

`null` and `undefined` don't have a `toString` or `valueOf` method. Afaik using `String` calls the `toString` method of its parameter (e.g. `String({})` => `[object Object]`).

Why do `String(null)` or `String(undefined` work then? It doesn't implicitly do `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)`. because that evaluates to `[object Null]`.

[edit]: from the spec ECMA-262/5th edition (page 48). This doesn't add to clarification, I'd say:

```
/*
Table 13 — ToString Conversions  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Argument Type  | Result  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Undefined      | "undefined"
Null           | "null"  
Boolean        | If the argument is true, then the result is "true".
...            | ...
*/
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After reviewing my previous answer, it seems a complete overhaul of my previous answer is necessary. I was way over complicating it, as the short answer is that these are standards-specified special cases.

The [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) for `String()` (`String` used as a function):

> 15.5.1.1 String ( [ value ] )
>
> Returns a String value (not a String object) computed by ToString(value). If value is not supplied, the empty 
>   String "" is returned.

The `ToString` function (that exists internally, not in userland) is defined as follows (9.8):

"The abstract operation ToString converts its argument to a value of type String according to Table 13"

```
Argument Type | Result
Null | "null"
Undefined | "undefined"
```

This means that `String(null)` and `String(undefined)` go into this special table of types and just return the string values valued `"null"` and `"undefined"`.

A user-land pseudo-implementation looks something like this:

```
function MyString(val) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (typeof val === "undefined") {
        return "undefined";
    } else if (val === null) {
        return "null";
    } else if (typeof val === "boolean") {
        return val ? "true" : "false";
    } else if (typeof val === "number") {
        // super complex rules
    } else if (typeof val === "string") {
        return val;
    } else {
        // return MyString(ToPrimitive(val, prefer string))
    }
}
```

(Note that this example ignores the constructor case (`new MyString()`) and that it uses user-land concepts rather than engine-land.)

---

I got a bit carried away and found an example implementation (V8 to be specific):

`string.js:`

```
// Set the String function and constructor.
%SetCode($String, function(x) {
  var value = %_ArgumentsLength() == 0 ? '' : TO_STRING_INLINE(x);
  if (%_IsConstructCall()) {
    %_SetValueOf(this, value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

`macros.py:`

```
macro TO_STRING_INLINE(arg) = (IS_STRING(%IS_VAR(arg)) ? arg : NonStringToString(arg));
```

`runtime.js:`

```
function NonStringToString(x) {
  if (IS_NUMBER(x)) return %_NumberToString(x);
  if (IS_BOOLEAN(x)) return x ? 'true' : 'false';
  if (IS_UNDEFINED(x)) return 'undefined';
  return (IS_NULL(x)) ? 'null' : %ToString(%DefaultString(x));
}
```

The NonStringToString (which is essentially what is of interest), is luckily defined in psuedo-JS-land.  As you can see, there is indeed a special case for null/true/false/undefined.

Comment: String() !== String(undefined) is because in JavaScript two objects are equal only if they are the same object in memory. When calling String() you are creating a wrapper object around the string primitive so essentially the comparison is of two different objects wrapping the same string primitive.

Comment: @Buzzy Yes, for objects that is correct, and thus for things like `new String(x) === new String(y)`, that would make sense. `String(x)` is specified to be equivalent to a a string value  though rather than a string object. According to the standard with regards to the `===` operator (11.9.6): "true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and 
same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false."

Comment: @Buzzy I'm glad you commented. After rereading my old answer, I realized it was way overcomplicating what is a very clear cut functionality in the specification! :)

Comment: makes this work, which is weird: `x={null:1}; x["null"];//1 x[null]; //1`

Answer (score 2):

There is probably just some extra checks and handling for special cases like `null` and `undefined`.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> It's possible to use String as a "safer" toString alternative, as although it still normally calls the underlying toString, it also works for null and undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`String(null)` creates a string object and passes it a default value of null.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in seeing the [*Annotated ES5*](http://es5.github.com/) (which is much more readable than the ECMAScript 5 PDF) which states that: `new String([ value ])` http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.2.1 calls `[ToString]` http://es5.github.com/#x9.8 (there is a table of the special convertion cases) to convert the value passed to it to a string.

Comment: It's the exact same table as I linked to, except for colored green in spots.  (And a direct link)