# empty string + null = "null"?

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

I came across an odd occurrence today while troubleshooting a rogue AJAX request in our application.  We send data back to the server, using `jQuery.param` to build the request string.

In one scenario, the object fed to the param function had a null option, so it looked something like this:

```
var myData = {
     x : 1,
     y : null
};
var params = jQuery.param(myData);
```

This code is actually buried in a backbone collection, but the principle is the same.

Now, I was completely shocked when the parameter, when received by the server, for the variable `y` was the literal string `"null"`, rather than being `null`.

After some digging, I found that `encodeURIComponent(null)` returns the string `"null"` and more interestingly `'' + null` yields `"null"` as well.  This was tested on Chrome 23, as well as Firefox 11.

The object ultimately being sent to the `jQuery.param` function gets built from arguments to a function, and null is a completely valid value for the parameter.  I got around it by just building the object with `y : param || ''`, but I'm curious as to the apparent wrongness of the native JS function, as well as why `'' + null = "null"`, since they are generally regarded as two different concepts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10362142/362536

Comment: Thanks @Brad.  This didn't show up in any of my searches.  Interesting example of the programming behind it, though I guess the decision had to be made somewhere when doing type conversion

Comment: I would consider that a bug in `jQuery.param`. `{foo: 'bar'}` should turn into `?foo=bar`, `{foo: ''}` should turn into `?foo=` and `{foo: null}` should turn into `?foo`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It's not a bug as long as jQuery's documentation doesn't claim that that is the expected behaviour, which is doesn't.

Comment: jQuery.param uses encodeURIComponent behind the scenes.  I agree that it should check for the variable to be null before running it through, but the real "bug" is in encodeURIComponent imo.

Comment: If you're going to say there's a bug here (which is debatable imho), then the bug is in the EcmaScript spec that says `null` becomes "null" when cast to a string.

Comment: Thanks @broofa.  For those wondering, the relevant section is here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` works as defined, which assumes a string input and produces string output. Casting `null` to a string in JavaScript does exactly as is defined, which is not intuitive, but necessary for historical reasons. jQuery, on the other hand, is not well defined for `null` and `undefined` as input values, as it implicitly assumes string input for all keys. To that effect @LightnessRacesinOrbit is correct in that the behavior isn't expected, but I still consider it to be a bug given how query strings work.

Comment: @zzzzBov jQuery apparently fixed this behavior in 1.8 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8653  It "correctly" would output "x=1&y=" from jQuery.param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overloaded `+` operator attempts to convert both operands to a common type before performing its operation. If either operand is a string, it converts both operands to a string and then performs string concatenation.

See the [ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) definition for the behavior of the `+` operator:

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

Comment: is that why encodeURIComponent works the same way?  Its implicitly joining strings at the end of it?

Comment: and I knew that type conversion took place, I just wasnt expecting `null` to be converted to `"null"` when that took place

Comment: The EcmaScript spec (section 15.1.3.4) specifies that the first thing encodeURIComponent() does is cast it's argument to a string.  Hence `null` becomes "null"